# Solr - Search Not Working

Tags: java, mysql, xml, solr

I am trying to run solr, but when i search for something, it wont show any result and just the name of the searched text. I have enclosed my solrconfig.xml, data-config.xml & schema.xml in these pastebin files

Solrconfig.xml - http://pastebin.com/rf4ASMCs

Data-Config.xml - http://pastebin.com/NLf8iKbd

Schema.xml - http://pastebin.com/Mtqqp5dn

Comment: Searching `qt=standard&q=*:*` yields nothing?

Comment: Please check that indexing completes successfully by looking at the status of `DataImportHandler`.  Also, please post the exact URL you are hitting and the response you get.

Comment: @Johan qt=standard&q=*:* returns all the fields but it also gives an error. Here is a screenshot of the output http://vvcap.net/db/byn48vTsje2_7IBIJmfp.htp

Comment: @Jasneet looks like that's working, what's the error?

Comment: @Karl the problem is I still can't search for particular keywords and also getting the error "the xml file does not appear to have any style information associated with it"

Comment: @Jasneet, please show a proper sample of your query, output where the full error is included.

Comment: @Johan http://pastebin.com/tHVpBtRw this is the output which comes when i run qt=standard&q=*:*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so we concluded that searching using `qt=standard&q=*:*` [works fine](http://pastebin.com/tHVpBtRw). Although it comes with a warning:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

The warning has **nothing** to do with Solr but rather your browser (or browser plugin) telling that there is [no associated style](http://www.w3.org/Style/styling-XML) information. Actually, this isn't even a warning, it's an overly verbose *information* message which you can **safely ignore**.